# How to get input from one bluetooth audio device profile and output from another

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio

Ive got a Bluetooth headset with a mic but i can only get good quality output from the high fidelity playback profiles with no input, or poorer quality with both input and output from the headset head unit profiles.

Is there a way to have the output from the high fidelity profile and the input from the headset head unit profile?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.